# Can you see history of off topic close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, migration

I'm not sure if there are [still problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116124/218740) with off topic votes, but I'm pretty sure I cast an off-topic vote with suggestion to migrate to superuser, and yet the question just got closed as off topic.

The OP actually emailed me because he couldn't understand.

Is anyone able to see what happened and why? [The question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16634371/2065121).

Comment: Most likely three or four of the other users who voted to close chose the general "off topic" without selecting a target site. You can see your own close vote history in your profile page, you have "votes" tab and "closure" filter.

Comment: I see - is there anything that can be done? It's a good question for superuser IMHO but do we have to vote to re-open it and then migrate or what?

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention and choose "Other" to explain however in this specific case moderator also reviewed and posted [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634371/continuous-backup-of-tens-of-millions-of-files#comment23974067_16634371): *The topic of this question is more geared toward Server Fault than Super User... **But**... this is not a question that is generally well-accepted on any Stack Exchange site, because is seems primarily to be a 'shopping' question*

Comment: Regarding what you asked, user can't vote to close twice; even if the question will be reopened you won't be able to vote to close it again.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ok, understood - thanks for the feedback.